# Declared datatype: invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, sqldatatypes

```
drop type name_Domain force;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE name_Domain AS OBJECT(
  FirstName VARCHAR2(30), 
  LastName varchar2(15)
);
```

---

```
   drop table Race;

   CREATE TABLE Race
   (
      RaceID ID_Domain, 
      Location name_Domain, 
   );
```

---

//new sql

```
ALTER TABLE Racecourse ADD CONSTRAINT pk_racecourse PRIMARY KEY (Name);
```

---->Error report:

```
   SQL Error: ORA-00904: "NAME": invalid identifier
   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

I am trying to set the constraint in a new sql file but the ORACLE SQL developer throws this error at me????????

Comment: There is no NAME column in your table - Oracle says this quite clear. What are you trying to reach ?

Comment: To elaborate on DmitryNikiforov's answer: you've got column names FirstName and LastName, but not Name - you probably want PRIMARY KEY (FirstName, LastName).

Comment: @DmitryNikiforov I am trying to use the Name-  drop table Race. This is the table I am work with... I am trying to set the colum Name as a primary key. 

    CREATE TABLE Racecourse 
    ( RaceID ID_Domain, 
      Name name_Domain);